# Puppet 3.0: am I supposed to be able to invoke a module from a similarly named subclass of another module?

Tags: puppet

I have a module named `drbd` which I need to use in another module named `hacluster`. Initially I thought to segregate drbd's stuff in its own class like this:

```
modules/drbd/[stuff]                # this is the DRBD module
modules/hacluster/manifests/init.pp # class hacluster { include hacluster::drbd }
modules/hacluster/manifests/drbd.pp # class hacluster::drbd
```

The `hacluster::drbd` class installs and configures DRBD like this:

```
class hacluster::drbd {
    class { 'drbd':
        service_ensure => undef,
        service_enable => false,
    }
    class { 'drbd::global_common':
        ...more stuff...
    }
    drbd::resource {'r0': ...stuff...}
    drbd::resource {'r1': ...stuff...}
}
```

...but Puppet doesn't like me invoking the drbd module from inside the hacluster::drbd class:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate declaration: Class[Hacluster::Drbd] is already declared; cannot redeclare on node mynode.blabla
```

I trivially fixed it by renaming my class from `hacluster::drbd` to `hacluster::drbdx`, but I'd still like to know if there is a way to call a module from a subclass of the same name contained in a different module. I did read the documentation but couldn't find out a definitive answer.

Comment: If you want to call something then you need to [define it](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_defined_types.html) not create a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puppet is preferring the class within the current namespace (`hacluster::`), instead of going back to the root and resolving from there.  There's a nice description in the language reference under [namespaces and autoloading](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_namespaces.html#relative-name-lookup-and-incorrect-name-resolution).

The solution is to explicitly reference the top-level namespace with `::` before the class name:

```
class { '::drbd':
    service_ensure => undef,
    service_enable => false,
}
```

Comment: I was going to comment "been there, done that" because that's exactly the first thing I tried and I still got the same error, so I went to the renaming route... but I re-tried it now before commenting and it did actually work as expected. My bad, I must have made some other mistake yesterday!